# Computing a projection of a $p$-adic plane curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers

Given a prime $p$ and a polynomial equation $f(x,y)=0$ with rational coefficients, I would like to obtain a precise description of the set of all numbers $y\in\mathbb Q_p$ such that the equation has a solution $x\in\mathbb Q_p$. Are there currently implemented methods for doing this?

Comment: It's a union of disks. To get a description of the disks, you need to know the description of the set of solutions to $f(x,y) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. What do mean by a description of that?

Comment: @FelipeVoloch, I mean the explicit description of this projection as a semi-algebraic subset of $\mathbb Q_p$, as defined, for instance, in Jan Denef's paper "p-adic semi-algebraic sets and cell decomposition".